# Creating List of Folders from File Names

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder containing many files named as such: `JBMA_23456.docx`, `JMRI_21456.docx`, `CM_22554.docx`, `QUA_11224.docx`. How do I create a sub-folder for each file bearing the same name as the file but without the `.docx` file extension? Additionally, I want to store the filename only as variables.

For example, I need to create a sub-folder named `JBMA_23456` from the document 
`JBMA_23456.docx`. Can anyone point me in teh right direction?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for %%A in (*.docx) do if not exist "%%~nA" md "%%~nA"
```

This creates a folder with the same name as each `.docx` file.

View modifiers in `for /?` or in `call /?`. The `n` modifier is the `name`.

Path modifiers:

`dpnx` is **d**rive, **p**ath, **n**ame and e**x**tension.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example batch file which attempts to perform the tasks as laid out in your question:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "BaseDir=C:\Users\Compo\Desktop\test"
Set "FileExt=.docx"

For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set var[ 2^>Nul') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where "%BaseDir%":*%FileExt% 2^>Nul') Do (Set /A i+=1
    Call Set "var[%%i%%]=%%~nA"
    If Exist "%%~dpA%%~nA\" (Echo Sub-Folder %%~nA already exists in %BaseDir%
    ) Else (Set /P "=Creating sub-folder %%~nA in %BaseDir%"<Nul
        MD "%%~dpA%%~nA">Nul 2>&1 && (Echo= was successful) || Echo= failed))
Set var[ 2>Nul
Pause
```

In order to use it, you would first ensure that the directory holding your files, *(excluding any trailing backslash)*, is placed between the **`=`** and **`"`** on line `4`, and the single file extension, *(including the leading period, **`.`**)*, similarly on line `5`.

Answer (score -1):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking for...

Anyway, here is the code i made

```
echo off
chcp 65001
cls
for /f "usebackq delims=." %%0 in (`dir /b "*.docx"`) do (
set filename=%%0
md %filename%
)
cmd /k
```

It creates a new folder for every file. Feel free to ask if this was not what you expected

Comment: "The syntax of the command is incorrect" is shown line from "set filename"

Comment: This can't work as it lacks delayed expansion! also don't use numbers as `for` variables, they are used to access arguments!